Vote, vote, vote!
This is basically a re-hash that goes back to the early days of this site and in fact to the core of SE.
I wish to encourage the community to vote early, and vote often. The reason I am bringing this up is that many questions and answers are being lost in the crowd without any upvotes (or downvotes). 
Why is this bad? The biggest problem with the scientific stacks is that they do not fit in well within the SE idea, namely, a question needs multiple answers and the vote score places the best one on top. Because many scientific questions have only one answer (or closely related answers) it is my strong impression that an existing answer is a strong repellent for other users to also answer it. Result: most questions receive only one answer, if any. If they are not voted upon, they end up in the pile w/o any marker of appreciation. Especially frustrating for the answerer. 
Let's vote a little more! Particularly because some of the high-voting members of this community have (partly) left the scene here.

Have you considered turning this into a features question? It may also be worth mentioning that there are badges for voting (e.g. at 600 votes).
